# Creating a javadoc web from compiled jar library

Tags: jar, javadoc

I have a third-party library in the form of a jar containing only class files.

I'd like to be able to run javadoc (or some other tool) and generate a reference to the library API calls that I can make.

I know I'm not going to get many useful comments, but I'm not expecting that. I just want the auto-generated summary of the classes and calls.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

EDIT: As good as jad is, it doesn't generate perfect code. Consequently, javadoc complains. Is there any way to tell javadoc to ignore the errors and generate documentation as best as it can?

Answer (score 2):

How about decompiling the classes and running javadoc on the output?

Try [jad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler)).

Comment: Been there, done that, am now doing a clean-room implementation of programs using the API :). I guess this'll work well, unless somebody else has another, simpler idea (not that this is complicated).

Comment: This only works if all classes decompile cleanly - javadoc complains about lots of unresolved references unless everything is there. Is there really nothing that can work directly on class files via reflection or somesuch?